# TypeScript – value of a union of object arrays produces intersection, not union

Tags: typescript

Having two arrays of different objects (array `a` and array `b`), the member value of a union of these arrays – `(a | b)[number]` – produces their intersection, while I would expect a union:

```
type a = { one: string }[];
type b = { one: string, two: string }[];

type ab = (a | b)[number]; // actual type:   { one: string }
                           // expected type: { one: string } | { one: string, two: string }
```

See also a [link to TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAhlC8UDeUD2A7CAuKBnYATgJboDmUAvgNoC6A3ALABQokUARgsmpjvsWQA0UYAHdUfQiXLV6zZq2gxOiABRwAPhwCUVdAFcAtuwgF6UAPQXYAY2D6YAGxHhsUdygxv%200ys3cBgUHBIVZQEAAekHYQACYukDievHhSZJRQWsneaaTCYhKpAjLMQA).

I would like to know:

1. Is the derived type `{ one: string }` correct?
2. Why it is not `{ one: string } | { one: string, two: string }`?
3. Is there a way of achieving the `expected` type for an arbitrary array of object arrays?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, derived type is correct, but usually not expected.

This is how union works in TS.

Consider next example:

```js
type a = { one: string };
type b = { one: string, two: string };

type ab = keyof (a | b); // "one"
```

TS will return `one` because this key is sharable between two types (a, b).

In order to achieve desired behaviour, you can try [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types):

> When conditional types act on a generic type, they become distributive when given a union type

```js
type a = { one: string }[];
type b = { one: string, two: string }[];

type ArrayValues<T> = T extends Array<infer Elem> ? Elem : never

type Result = ArrayValues<a | b> // { one: string } | { one: string, two: string }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAhlC8UDeUD2A7CAuKBnYATgJboDmUAvgNoC6A3ALABQokUARgsmpjvsWQA0UYAHdUfQiXLV6zZq2gBBAgRggAajAA2AVwi4APABUAfF2NQIAD2AR0AE1xQVakIZIAzCASgBRbQgAW3MAfn9AoKgcTAA3H3kWcGgAJQNdbWAuV3UtPQNDOAAfDlNEoA)

Comment: Awesome, Thanks! The TS behavior feels really unintuitive in this case.

Comment: Here https://catchts.com/ you can find some interesting types